# awk - assign variables from multiple sources

Tags: awk, grep

I want to print the output which is the combination of multiple file content.

Example:

```
grep -v 'word' FILE_A | awk -v var1="string1" -v var2="string2" -v var3="string3"   
 '{ print $1 var1 var2 var3}'
```

I can do this with the command above: assign specific strings to variables and print it with the `grep`'ed content.
However if `string1/2/3`'s are long it's quite complicated to assign such long words.

Question:

If I would write `string1/2/3` as single lines to a `File_B` how can I assign such File_B lines as variables?

Example:

```
cat File_B
string1
string2
string3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just put it all in an `awk` script instead of just the variables:

```bsh
$ cat script.awk 
!/word/ {
    var1="string1"
    var2="string2"
    var3="string3longlonglonglonglonglong"
    print $1,var1,var2,var3
}

$ cat file
word no match
match1 
word no match
match2 match 123

$ awk -f script.awk file
match1 string1 string2 string3longlonglonglonglonglong
match2 string1 string2 string3longlonglonglonglonglong
```

You never need to combine `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: Why I am getting 4 same outputs?  

Even when using simple script `{var="string" print var}` I get `string \n string \n string \n`. Why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have 4 lines in the input file and the block `{var="string" print var}` is applied to every line.